# how to insert value in mysql databases usig ibatis

Tags: java, mysql, ibatis

When I insert data in to Mysql using ibatis I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No SqlMapClient specified
>       at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:90)
>       at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.execute(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:155)
>       at org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientTemplate.insert(SqlMapClientTemplate.java:317)
>       at com.dao.ContactDAOImpl.insert(ContactDAOImpl.java:64)
>       at com.dao.Main.main(Main.java:26)

Anyone knows why is this Error is getting displayed?

Comment: Please update the question by telling how are you trying to insert  data...

Answer (score 0):

It means, you haven't configured the ibatis sqlmapclient bean in spring.
You'll have to share your Java code + ibatis sqlmap config file + spring config xml for more info. 
But I would start by looking at the spring config file, and seeing if ibatis has been properly configured.